# "dispatch" v "despatch"

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, homophones

Using it in the example of:

> Can you log *despatch* and delivery of documents?

Three questions:

1. Is *despatch* a misspelling of *dispatch* that made its way into the dictionary? Could I use *dispatch* instead in the above example?
2. Do you pronounce both of them the same?
3. Are they a *homophone* of one another?

Comment: General Reference. They're just alternate spellings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is despatch a misspelling of dispatch that made its way into the dictionary? Could I use dispatch instead in the above example**? "Dispatch" is the most common, and therefore most preferred, spelling, but both spellings appear side by side in the revered *Oxford English Dictionary* (see the work cited entry below). "Despatch" isn't a misspelling, just a less preferred spelling.

**Do you pronounce both of them the same?**  These words are really two spellings of the same word; therefore, the two spellings share one pronunciation.

**Are they a homophone of one another?**  The two spellings have the same pronunciations, but may not qualify as homophones because they are, in fact, the same word spelled two ways.

**Work Cited**

"dispatch | despatch, n.". *OED Online*. December 2012. Oxford University Press. 5 March 2013.